# Two professors agreed to be my supervisor

Tags: thesis, supervision, professionalism

I did my research for masters degree under an aged professor. He was a very good guide. From a Ph. D. research student under the same professor, I came to know that my guide has only 2-3 years left before retiring. I was planning to enroll for Ph D after a brief working in industry. So, since my guide might be retired by the time I come back, I asked another professor, who is also very good, for being my guide in Ph D, and he agreed. Now, by the end of my masters course, I asked my current guide about how many years he is here, and he said he still has 6 years of work before retirement. I told him that I might come back for Ph D after a year, and he assumed that I want to work under him.

Now, I am thinking of going back to my institute after a year, but I am a bit scared whom shall I approach and if I end up offending the other one. Actually, both of them are very good, and it's difficult to choose, but I might want to work with my masters guide only, as I got comfortable working with him.

So, I want to know if I did anything unethical (unknowingly), that might create problem for me or offend any of the professors.

Comment: Do they work in similar/complementary topics? Would they like to share a PhD candidate (more than a member of the exam committee)? Do their current universities' policies align  with this? By your elected alias, e.g. there are international *cotutuelles* ([Sorbonne](http://www.univ-paris3.fr/la-cotutelle-de-these-23217.kjsp), [Evry](https://www.univ-evry.fr/international/personnel-de-luniversite-devry/mettre-en-place-une-cotutuelle-de-these.html); and though more an coordinating body than an establishment of research [UFA](https://www.dfh-ufa.org/fr/vous-etes/doctorant/cotutelle-de-these).)

Comment: Are they at the same institution? If not, do they consider themselves colleagues/collaborators?

Comment: This may depend on your field. In mathematics, it's easy for two professors to jointly supervise a student. In an experimental science, each professor may need you to work full-time in his lab, and you can't do that for both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your PhD supervisor is usually a fairly close relationship. Usually a professional one, but still close. You are meant to trust them for your professional development.

It's also nice if you can be personally friends with them, though that does not always happen. This can be very different in different cultures. In some schools it will be super-duper-business-at-all-times. In other schools you will likely get invited to social events such as parties at your prof's house. One day I found myself holding my prof's 18-month old son and offering to change his poopy diaper. Your mileage may vary. (Mrs. Prof saved me from that little task.)

So you want to be sure you are as open and honest with them as you can manage. Confusion over who is meant to be your supervisor is not a good start.

I don't think it was unethical. It seems like you just managed to get some confusion into the messages you sent to two profs. It happens.

What would quite likely to be unethical is leaving it confused. For example, if one of these profs falsely thinks he has you as a student, he might turn down some other student. That could get a lot of angry looks in your direction. It would certainly be a poor basis for the relationship with your prof.

My suggestion is to communicate to both profs that you may have things confused. Let them know what you have let us know in this post. Let them know you are concerned to not offend either of them.

If these two profs work in sufficiently close subjects that either could supervise you, it is quite likely they know each other. At least by reputation.

When I started my PhD I went to a prof I had thought to work with. After a 20 minute conversation he suggested that another prof in the same department would be a better fit. Turns out he was giving me to one of his former PhD students, now a prof.

If they both know you are interested, they may do that sort of thing. And it could work out well since the "other" prof, knowing your interest, may come by to lend a hand now and then.