# Should I explain reason to a professor whom I asked fr supervision earlier, but joined PhD for another professor?

Tags: supervision

This is a continuation of [a question I asked a year ago](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/190015/two-professors-agreed-to-be-my-supervisor).

My masters supervisor contacted me to starting new work, and I returend to  my institute to start my PhD.

I am feeling a bit confused if I should explain to the other professor who also agreed to be my supervisor, the real reason for this situation, or shall I just leave the topic, as I am sure he will never ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a good idea just to have a chat with the other professor. Academia is a small place and you will definitely run into him one way or the other. Most professor won’t take it negatively if you decide to join some other professor. In long term, it’s good to clear the air

Comment: Thanks. I cleared the air. He laughed and seemed a bit unhappy with me. I guess it will be ok in the long run.

Comment: I assure you that the unhappiness would be because of losing a good student but he will appreciate you talking to him and clarifying